# 'required' validation for dropdown

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have to validate a dropdown using `required` validation in AngularJS. I have created directives for validation but directive is not loaded on select tag. How to load directive on dropdown? Or, how to validate a dropdown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a validation method on the submit button of your form to check the value of your dropdown.

Example : http://plnkr.co/edit/PbePIh

app.js :

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.colors = [{name: 'blue'}, {name:'red'}, {name:'yellow'}];

  $scope.reqColor = function() {
    if ($scope.color && $scope.color.name && $scope.color.name != 'blue') return false;
    return true;
  }
});
```

index.html :

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
 <form name="form">
  <select ng-model="color" ng-options="c.name for c in colors"></select><br>
  <button ng-disabled="form.$invalid || reqColor()">Save</button>
 </form>
</body>
```

In this example, the save button will be disabled if you didn't select anything in the dropdown or if you selected the color blue.